# Technique for reading in multiple lines for Haskell IO

Tags: haskell, io

Basically I would like to find a way so that a user can enter the number of test cases and then input their test cases. The program can then run those test cases and print out the results in the order that the test cases appear.

So basically I have main which reads in the number of test cases and inputs it into a function that will read from IO that many times. It looks like this:

```
main = getLine >>= \tst -> w (read :: String -> Int) tst [[]]
```

This is the method signature of w: `w :: Int -> [[Int]]-> IO ()`

So my plan is to read in the number of test cases and have w run a function which takes in each test case and store the result into the [[]] variable. So each list in the list will be an output. w will just run recursively until it reaches 0 and print out each list on a separate line. I'd like to know if there is a better way of doing this since I have to pass in an empty list into w, which seems extraneous.

Comment: What do you mean by "store the result in the `[[]]` variable"?  `[[]]` isn't a variable, it's an immutable value just like all other Haskell values.  If you're wanting to read in a specific number of lines, you can use `Control.Monad.replicateM n getLine`, where `n` is the number of lines you want to read in.

Comment: So I would keep appending the result to that list of lists and at the end I would print all of it out. I am at a loss because I am not able to return a list of lists and use IO() types at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @bheklilr mentioned you can't update a value like `[[]]`. The standard functional approach is to pass an accumulator through a a set of recursive calls. In the following example the `acc` parameter to the `loop` function is this accumulator - it consists of all of the output collected so far. At the end of the loop we return it.

```
myTest :: Int -> [String]
myTest n = [ "output line " ++ show k ++ " for n = " ++ show n | k <- [1..n] ]

main = do
  putStr "Enter number of test cases: "
  ntests <- fmap read getLine :: IO Int
  let loop k acc | k > ntests = return $ reverse acc
      loop k acc = do
        -- we're on the kth-iteration
        putStr $ "Enter parameter for test case " ++ show k ++ ": "
        a <- fmap read getLine :: IO Int
        let output = myTest a         -- run the test
        loop (k+1) (output:acc)
  allOutput <- loop 1 []
  print allOutput
```

As you get more comfortable with this kind of pattern you'll recognize it as a *fold* (indeed a monadic fold since we're doing IO) and you can implement it with `foldM`.

*Update*: To help explain how fmap works, here are equivalent expressions written without using `fmap`:

```
With fmap:                                 Without fmap:

n <- fmap read getLine :: IO [Int]         line <- getLine
                                           let n = read line :: Int

vals <- fmap (map read . words) getLine    line <- getLine
             :: IO [Int]                   let vals = (map read . words) line :: [Int]
```

Using `fmap` allows us to eliminate the intermediate variable `line` which we never reference again anyway. We still need to provide a type signature so `read` knows what to do.

Comment: lets say I want to parse a string into an array of integers. Should I do something like `fmap read $ words getLine :: [IO Int]` ??

Comment: Thanks. Question about the `:: IO [Int]` part. How do I interpret it? is it saying that fmap will return something of IO [Int]? Then we use the `<-` to strip the IO away?

Comment: That's correct. I've updated the answer to help explain how fmap works here.

Comment: Awesome thanks. One more question if I may, `(map read . words)` is the function to be mapped onto getLine? How would I interpret `map read . words`? Is it expecting some [Char] input which will then be changed to [[Char]] and will then have read mapped over it?

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way is to use `replicateM`:

```
runAllTests :: [[Int]] -> IO ()
runAllTests = {- ... -}

main = do
    numTests <- readLn
    tests <- replicateM numTests readLn
    runAllTests tests
-- or:
-- main = readLn >>= flip replicateM readLn >>= runAllTests
```